# Models that can learn incrementally

Tags: classification, scikit-learn

I want to implement a multinomial text classifier for my 3 classes 'A', 'B' and 'C'. This classifier should be open, in the sense that it should be extensible with new data.
Using the hashing trick it is possible to avoid being bounded by the original text (modulo collisions).

Is it possible to successfully train such a classifier if the number of classes is not known in advance? I am thinking of a streaming data case, where is not possible to look at the data before training.

For example some classifiers in `scikit-learnimplement` implement the  `partial_fit` method, but they seem to require the number of total classes.

Comment: You might have some luck searching "online learning Dirichlet process," and papers that cite the papers you find.

Comment: Such algorithms are commonly called "online" algorithms, Try appending "online" to your search queries.